# URLLib with cert SSLv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, urllib

I'm using Python 3.7.3 and the requests_pkcs12 library to scrape a website where I must pass a certificate and password, then download and extract zip files from links on the page.  I've got the first part working fine.  But when I try to read the files using urllib, I get an error.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests_pkcs12 import get

# get page and setup BeautifulSoup
# r = requests.get(url) # old non-cert method
r = get(url, pkcs12_filename=certpath, pkcs12_password=certpwd)

# find zip files to download
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# Read files
i = 1
for td in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='td' and tag.text.strip().endswith('DAILY.zip')):
    link = td.find_next('a')
    print(td.get_text(strip=True), link['href'] if link else '')  # good
    zipurl = 'https:\\my.downloadsite.com" + link['href'] if link else ''
    print (zipurl)  # good
    # Read zip file from URL    
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(zipurl)  # ERROR on this line SSLv3 alert handshake failure
    zippedData = url.read()
```

I've seen various older posts with Python 2.x on ways to handle this, but wondering what the best way to do this now, with new libraries in Python 3.7.x.

Below is the stack trace of the error.

[image: Here is the stack of the error:]

Comment: A handshake error can be almost everything, from failing to provide the expected certificate to no shared ciphers to wrong protocol ... . It is impossible to say what exactly is going on here and how to fix. Are there more specific error messages, stack traces etc?

Comment: Stack trace has been added to the question.

Comment: Thanks, although in this case it unfortunately does not narrow down the problem enough. Could you do a packet capture of the connection so that one can see at which stage of the TLS handshake it breaks ? You can use for example wireshark for this. If it breaks early it is likely a cipher or protocol problem. If it breaks late after receiving the certificate from the server it is likely a problem with the client certificates you use.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that complicated. This code works fine for an HTTP site, and downloads the zip file just fine. Since this site requires a cert, the only change was replacing the requests.get with the requests_pkcs12 get, passing the cert and password.  That part works fine.  I'm just wondering if you need to change the urllib.request.urlopen as well to handle the fact that it's an HTTPS site.  That seems to be the only issue.

Comment: This is an issue in the TLS handshake. There is no TLS handshake with plain HTTP so it cannot be an issue with plain HTTP. The result of your seemingly small code change is using a complex protocol with many new error scenarios instead of a simple protocol. *"I'm just wondering if you need to change the urllib.request.urlopen as well to handle the fact that it's an HTTPS site"* - it handles https well. But if you need a client certificate to access the zip file too (which is unknown) then it will not magically be propagated from your initial `get`.

Comment: So, assuming I do need to use my client certificate to access the zip file even after my initial get, how can that be done using urllib.request.urlopen ?  Or should I be using some other method to access the zip file?

Comment: Why not just use `requests_pkcs12` in this place too?

Comment: Exactly!  That was the simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to not use urllib and instead use the same requests replacement that allows a pfx and password passed to it.

Last 2 lines:

```
url = urllib.request.urlopen(zipurl)  # ERROR on this line SSLv3 alert handshake failure
zippedData = url.read()
```

should be replaced with:

```
from requests_pkcs12 import get, post
certpath = "c:/certs/cert1.pfx"
certpwd = "mypassword1234"
:
:
url = get(zipurl, pkcs12_filename=certpath, pkcs12_password=certpwd)
zippedData = url.content
```